# How can I make this react input component idiomatic?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom-events, react-hooks

Here's a react input component:

```js
function Input({ value, setValue }) {
  return (
    <div>
      <input value={value} onChange={event => setValue(event.target.value)} />
      <button onClick={() => setValue(value.toUpperCase())}>Capitalize</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

It's just a vanilla input component together with a button that capitalizes the input's value. It's meant to be controlled by some parent component:

```js
function Parent() {
  let [value, setValue] = useState("");
  return <Input value={value} setValue={setValue} />;
}
```

This works fine, but it's not *idiomatic*. To be useable as a "drop-in replacement" for a vanilla input component, it should take an `onChange` prop, not `setValue`, the relevant difference being that `onChange` takes a synthetic event as an argument while `setValue` takes a string. (I'd like the presence of the capitalize button to be "opaque" to a developer using this `Input` component.)

I tried to idiomaticize this (see snippet below) by having the input element fire off a change event when the button is clicked, but the this doesn't cause `onChange` to execute. (I assume that this is due to details of react's synthetic event system that I don't understand. I browsed a bunch of posts on this topic, but couldn't get the ideas I found to work.)

```js
function AnotherInput({ value, onChange }) {
  let input = useRef();

  let handleClick = () => {
    input.current.value = value.toUpperCase();

    var event = new Event("change" /* also tried "input" */, {
      bubbles: true
    });

    input.current.dispatchEvent(event); // onChange doesn't fire!
  };
  return (
    <div>
      <input value={value} ref={input} onChange={onChange} />
      <button onClick={handleClick}>Capitalize</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Also, I feel I shouldn't have to use a `ref` here because I don't want to modify the DOM directly; I just want to change the value in the controlling parent component.

[Here's a CodePen.](https://codepen.io/mgreenbe/pen/vYBGONE?editors=1010)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made it work by simulating the `event Object` on the Capitalize Button.

Parent Component:

```
function Parent() {
    let [value, setValue] = useState("");
    return <Input value={value} onChange={(e) => setValue(e.target.value)} />;
}
```

Input Component:

**EDITED:** I've managed to came up with a more elegant solution to the Input Component:

```
 function Input({ value, onChange: inheritedOnChange }) {
    return (
        <div>
            <input value={value} onChange={inheritedOnChange} />
            <button value={value.toUpperCase()} onClick={inheritedOnChange}>Capitalize</button>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Note that i renamed the `onChange` prop to `inheritedOnChange` just for readability purposes. Preserving the onChange name at the destructuring should still work.

Comment: Your second solution is especially clever! I didn't know that `button` tags have `value` attributes. The target of the event passed to `onChange` will vary (`input` or `button`), but that seems quite reasonable, accurately reflecting the source of the event...

Comment: Also, it the definition of `onChange` on the parent for the second example (not in @Japsz's snippet), you need to read `event.currentTarget.value` and not, simply, `event.target.value`. (This cost me 20 minutes.)